# How to make a tile background in react native?

Tags: react-native

I googled a lot but cannot find any solution for this simple problem. The only thing I could come up with is making a `for loop` to cover the whole screen with one image repeatedly, but this way is totally crazy. Can anyone give me a good direction for this ?